# Animator.SetBool() breaks NavMeshAgent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two animations set to my zombie. One is the walk animation when the zombie isn't aware of the player and the other is the running animation when the zombie becomes aware of the player.

I also have a Navigation Mesh and each zombie has a NavMeshAgent component attached to it.

The walking animation works fine and sticks to the boundaries of the mesh. 
But when the zombie becomes aware, I'm using the Animator.SetBool() function to transition into the running animation.

The transition breaks the agent in the sense that it just continues running off of the mesh after running towards the player.

I'm new to Unity so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Here's the code:

```
private void Update()
{
        if(isAware)
        {
            navAgent.SetDestination(player.position);
            animator.SetBool("Aware", true);
            navAgent.speed = chaseSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            SearchPlayer();
            Wander();
            animator.SetBool("Aware", false);
            navAgent.speed = wanderSpeed;
        }
    }

    public void SearchPlayer()
    {
        if (Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, transform.InverseTransformPoint(player.position)) < view / 2f)
        {
            if(Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position) < viewDist)
            {
                OnAware();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnAware()
    {
        isAware = true;
    }

    /*
     * Create random points on the Navigation Mesh for the zombies to aimlessly wander to
     */
    private Vector3 WanderingPoint()
    {
        Vector3 randomPoint = (Random.insideUnitSphere * 4f) + transform.position; // Create a random point in a sphere surrouding the zombie
        NavMeshHit navHit;
        NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomPoint, out navHit, 7f, -1); //Get nearest point on the Navigation Mesh to the random point generated in the sphere around the zombie so that it stays within the mesh

        return new Vector3(navHit.position.x, transform.position.y, navHit  .position.z); 


    }

    private void Wander()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, wanderPoint) < 2f) //Create new Wandering Point when zombie reaches the current wandering point
        {
            wanderPoint = WanderingPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            navAgent.SetDestination(wanderPoint);
        }
    }
```

Here's the Animator window [image: screenshot].

Comment: normally you use velocity to determine run or walk.. setting a boolean on the animator wont break navmesh unless you are doing something wonky

Comment: you need to share more informations. about the animator configuration and the code. it's impossible to help you with so little info

Comment: @LiefLayer I've added some code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a first look the code part is fine. the problem could be in the Animator part.
if in the Z_Run state there is no idle animation (only a running animation) where the zombie reach the player he cannot stop running (I'm not sure if that's the problem, you need to be more specific on that part). 
Also, to make the animation smooth, I suggest that when your navAgent reach "near" the player it should decrease the speed, before decrease the speed again to zero when it actually reach it and turn to idle animation (you should be able to do the last part in the Z_Run state if you use a basic Blend Trees as a state).
Just take a look at the docs of Unity about Blend Trees.

Comment: There's no idle animation. But the thing is when he reaches the player, the colliders stop working as well and he goes through the player and continues running off of the mesh

Comment: If i comment out Animator.SetBool, then everything works fine. Like the zombie will walk towards the player and it won't pass through the player

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva Right now the problem is not really solved. You are just using the navAgent and the Etc_Walk_Zombie_01 everywhere. The problem really is the lack of idle animation because your zombie need to change the animation when he reach the player. If you try to use a running animation when the zombie should stop it will try to move in contrast with the nav agent so it will display a strange behaviour. Try to use a Blend Tree like I said if you really wish to solve the problem, if not you can delete the Run state

Comment: I see. I'll give that a try :)

Comment: Hello @LiefLayer, sorry again. I just did a little testing and noticed this. My walk and running animations are from two different sources. I noticed that all the animations from where I got running one give me the problem. The animations where I got the walking one all work fine with my code. What would you make of this?

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva I'm not 100% sure, I don't make any animations or models like most developers. But I know a few things about animations in unity3d. 1. The animation should be unity3d mecanim compatible, when I used Unity3d version 3 there was not a standard Skeletal animation bones and every animation was just a clip (it didn't affect the physics of the model, so even when you played the walk animation the model would not move, it would just move on the spot)... after version 4 they made mecanim and animator for humanoid models so that you can use animations of different characters if they all

Comment: follow the same skeleton. You need to be sure that the animation you are using use the same skeleton and that it is compatible with Unity3d mecanim standard. 2. You need to configure the animation for your current model, if the animation is, for example, rotated by 180° when you apply it to your model you need to correct that before using it. 3. You can just try to use Mixamo animations on your model, they are free and 100% unity3d compatible and royalty free. I think that's the best way to handle the problem.